# custom keys sorting in rolled data d3.js

Tags: javascript, sorting, csv, d3.js, nested

I try to sort keys of nested data taken from a csv file using `d3.js`. The thing is, that it's not possible at this case to sort by `d3.ascending` or `d3.descending` because my values are strings.

I found example, which fits my needs:

```
var priority_order = ['MUST', "SHOULD", 'COULD', 'WISH'];

var nested_data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.status; })
    .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
    .key(function(d) { return d.priority; })
    .sortKeys(function(a,b) { return priority_order.indexOf(a) - priority_order.indexOf(b); })
    .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
    .entries(csv_data);
```

But it doesn't work when I use it. I don't get well the idea of `function(a,b) { return priority_order.indexOf(a) - priority_order.indexOf(b); }`.

I use the code, which looks like this:

```
var S6_order = ['city 20 000 - 49 999 citizens', 
          'city 50 000 – 99 999 citizens', 
          'city 100 000 – 199 999 citizens', 
          'city 200 000 – 499 999 citizens', 
          'city above 500 000 citizens'];

var S6_sort = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.S6; })
    .sortKeys(function(a,b) { return S6_order.indexOf(a) - S6_order.indexOf(b); })
    .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
    .entries(data);
```

A piece of data I use:

```
S2,S6,P35,P2_1,P2_2,P2_3,P2_4,P2_5
2-9 persons,city 20 000 - 49 999 citizens,I like very much,too less,too much,too much,too less,just right
10-49 persons,city 100 000 – 199 999 citizens,I like very much,too much,I don't know,I don't know,I don't know,I don't know
2-9 persons,city 200 000 – 499 999 citizens,I like very much,accurately,too less,too less,too less,just right
10-49 persons,city 50 000 – 99 999 citizens,I do not like neither dislike,too less,too much,too much,too less,too less
10-49 persons,city above 500 000 citizens,I rather like,too less,accurately,accurately,accurately,just right
only me,city above 500 000 citizens,I rather like,too less,too less,accurately,accurately,too less
2-9 persons,city 200 000 – 499 999 citizens,I like very much,accurately,accurately,accurately,accurately,just right
only me,city 50 000 – 99 999 citizens,I rather like,accurately,accurately,accurately,accurately,just right
50-249 persons,city 100 000 – 199 999 citizens,I like very much,accurately,too less,too less,accurately,just right
10-49 persons,city 100 000 – 199 999 citizens,I rather like,too less,accurately,accurately,accurately,just right
2-9 persons,city 100 000 – 199 999 citizens,I rather like,accurately,accurately,too less,accurately,just right
2-9 persons,city 50 000 – 99 999 citizens,I rather like,I don't know,accurately,accurately,too less,just right
only me,city 20 000 - 49 999 citizens,I like very much,accurately,accurately,accurately,I don't know,too much
2-9 persons,city above 500 000 citizens,I like very much,too less,accurately,too much,too less,too less
10-49 persons,city above 500 000 citizens,I like very much,accurately,accurately,accurately,accurately,too less
2-9 persons,city 200 000 – 499 999 citizens,I rather like,accurately,accurately,accurately,accurately,just right
2-9 persons,city 100 000 – 199 999 citizens,I like very much,accurately,accurately,accurately,accurately,just right
10-49 persons,city 50 000 – 99 999 citizens,I do not like neither dislike,accurately,accurately,accurately,accurately,just right
2-9 persons,city 50 000 – 99 999 citizens,I like very much,accurately,accurately,accurately,accurately,just right
2-9 persons,city 100 000 – 199 999 citizens,raczej go nie lubię,too less,too much,too much,I don't know,I don't know
2-9 persons,city above 500 000 citizens,I like very much,too less,accurately,accurately,accurately,too less
2-9 persons,city 50 000 – 99 999 citizens,I rather like,too much,accurately,accurately,accurately,just right
10-49 persons,city above 500 000 citizens,I do not like neither dislike,too much,accurately,too much,accurately,I don't know
50-249 persons,city 200 000 – 499 999 citizens,I rather like,I don't know,accurately,accurately,too less,just right
2-9 persons,city above 500 000 citizens,I rather like,too much,accurately,accurately,too less,just right
2-9 persons,city 200 000 – 499 999 citizens,I rather like,accurately,accurately,accurately,accurately,just right
10-49 persons,city above 500 000 citizens,I rather like,too less,too less,accurately,I don't know,too less
2-9 persons,city 200 000 – 499 999 citizens,I do not like neither dislike,I don't know,I don't know,too much,accurately,I don't know
10-49 persons,city 200 000 – 499 999 citizens,I rather like,too much,accurately,too much,accurately,just right
```

I load these with:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(file) {
    data = file.map(function(d) {
        return {
            "S2": d.S2,
            "S6": d.S6,
            "P2_1": d.P2_1,
            "P2_2": d.P2_2,
            "P2_3": d.P2_3,
            "P2_4": d.P2_4,
            "P2_5": d.P2_5
            };
        });    
    });
```

Comment: post what is your data and in the example which is working csv_data.

Comment: OK, I've added those.

Comment: check http://plnkr.co/edit/7GkpwqKBAc13sm8PLl3l?p=preview - does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks D3_GXT_Java! Your example worked fine on Plunker, but I tried it locally and it again didn't. But I figured it out! The thing was, that dashes in my data weren't plain ones but em dashes (â€“), that messed the whole thing! After changing them everything works smooth. Great lesson for the future. Thanks a lot!